# Merge tags - AC and Air Conditioning?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I have been working on putting some information in the tags. I see there are tags for both AC and for Air Conditioning. Can we merge these as tag synonyms? Probably under the AC moniker, but whichever works.

Comment: So what tag should be used for cars made by the AC company?

Comment: @Chenmunka ... If we ever get a question about [AC Cars Ltd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_Cars), it can be put under [tag:ac-cars] or [tag:auto-carriers] to cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done! The Master Tag is [ac](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac) and [air-conditioning](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning) is the synonym. I would have preferred it the opposite way because AC can also mean Alternating Current, but that tag wouldn't get much use here so I don't have a problem with it as it is.

Comment: Can we add `hvac` as a synonym as well?

Comment: @zaid HVAC refers to the whole system including the duct work heater core etc.

Comment: Right, it includes the radiator/condenser, evaporator, compressor, throttle valve, refrigerant, heater core and ductwork. Not sure why a distinction is being made between `ac` and `hvac` since the same components/sub-systems are involved.

Comment: @Zaid AC is more specific that HVAC if I have a problem with the AC compressor or the AC system not cooling it's AC. If I have a problem with the heater core, blower motor, cabin air filter blend air doors, the control head etc it's HVAC. AC is just AC, while HVAC is the whole system